# Regex: Trying to grab text inside quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

`<img class="img-thumbnail thumb" style="width:100px;height:100px;" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQMCgsOCwkJDRENDgBAQjKv+I1atf2Q==" class="img-thumbnail thumb" style="width:100px;height:100px;"`

and I just want to grab 
`data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQMCgsOCwkJDRENDgBAQjKv+I1atf2Q==`

I've tried multiple attempts on regexr. I'm a bit stuck and so far I have 
src="(.*)". I'm not sure how to get it to stop at that next quote.

https://regexr.com/53gio

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) api

```js
let str = `<img class="img-thumbnail thumb" style="width:100px;height:100px;" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQMCgsOCwkJDRENDgBAQjKv+I1atf2Q==" class="img-thumbnail thumb" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />`

let parser = new DOMParser()
let parsed = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");

[...parsed.getElementsByTagName('img')].forEach(v=>{
  console.log(v.src)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me

```
src="([^"]*)"
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the lazy (?) qualifier to grab as few characters as possible and then end on the quote.

```
src="(.*?)"
```